# stop alarm for a specific time interval

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

i set daily alarm in my app.
up to now all is fine.But now what i want is  alarm is remain silent for specific time interval.
I mad alarm activity which call at every 30 mins. Now for e.g. If i set 11 pm to 4 am then alarm should remain silent between 11 pm to 4 pm. 
code for this is like:

```
Calendar currentTime = new GregorianCalendar();
        currentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR,Hour);// EXtra Added
        currentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Minute);
        currentTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, Calendar.SECOND);
        currentTime.set(Calendar.DATE, Calendar.DATE);
        currentTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH);


        Calendar start_time = new GregorianCalendar();
        start_time.set(Calendar.HOUR, sHour);// EXtra Added
        start_time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, sMinute);
    //  start_time.set(Calendar.SECOND, Calendar.SECOND);
    //  start_time.set(Calendar.DATE, Calendar.DATE);
    //  start_time.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH);

        Calendar end_time = new GregorianCalendar();
        end_time.set(Calendar.HOUR, eHour);// EXtra Added
        end_time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, eMinute);
    //  end_time.set(Calendar.SECOND, Calendar.SECOND);
    //  end_time.set(Calendar.DATE, Calendar.DATE);
    //  end_time.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH);



if(!SILENCE)
{

    fireAlarm(Hour, Minute);
}
else if((start_time.getTimeInMillis()<=System.currentTimeMillis())&& (System.currentTimeMillis()<=end_time.getTimeInMillis() ) )
{
    System.out.println("You Are in Silent Mode");
    SIlent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}else{
    fireAlarm(Hour,Minute);
}
```

so give me a solution that i can fix it .
Thanx.

Comment: alarmManager is the better way to do this. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: i am using alarm manager .but dosent work for me. all is working good but i only want to set specific time interval in between alarm should remain silent.

Comment: this is a simple example                                 LONG_INTERVAL = 15; // interval in minutes

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, START_TIME, LONG_INTERVAL * 60000, sender);

Comment: already done with it and it works , After time interval of 30 mins my alarm rings .But what i want to do is that if i set 11 pm to 4 am then in between alarm should be silent and after that it should ring with 30 min interval.

Comment: you can set interval to 30min as it is, how about canceling alarm(11pm) and set new alarm when you change it to 4am?